# Compiling a C library into a DLL with MinGW

Tags: java, dll, mingw, jna

I'm trying to use the [librsync library](http://librsync.sourceforge.net/) in my java program trough the JNA. For this i need to be able to compile the librsync library into a dll. I know how to compile a single c file into a dll using MinGW and for this i have found lots of examples but i'm at a loss on how to do it for a large library like librsync. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Since you're going to need compilation anyway, you may as well use [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) instead of JNA... :) FYI, we can use MinGW by calling the `Builder` with `java -jar javacpp.jar -properties mingw-x86`

Comment: Via MinGW Shell, go to librsync's extracted distribution folder and type: `./configure` and `make all check`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything specific about librsync, but you should be able to use ld or gcc --shared as normal. However, when you try to build big libraries with lots of dependencies it is ofen *very* much simpler if you can use the existing Makefile, and only make small modifications to it.

So your first step would be to see that it builds under MinGW as it is, then go ahead and try to modify the Makefile to make a dll

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

1. Create your own .def file exporting the various `rs*` functions you need from `librsync`: [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. Run `dlltool` and then gcc to generate the .dll file you need: [Source](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/dlltool.html)